# Can CPU Throttling results in OOMKilled states in k8s?

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, out-of-memory

My pod is running in k8s and restarts every 20-30 hours, caused by an `OOMKilled` error, here are the configured limits:

```
  limits:
    cpu: 600m
    memory: 1536Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 150m
    memory: 1536Mi
```

In the container is a JVM (Spring Boot) running with the following Options:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1G -Xdebug -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=26
```

**Analysis of the JVM Metrics**

From my point of view, I can see, that there is a load peak, but not high enough to reach the memory limits, however the CPU Usage increases rapidly:
[image]

**Analysis of the Pod Metrics**

Let me show you the metrics of the pod provided by k8s:
[image]

Memory increases much more than in the JVM shows. CPU Throttling is active. But I do not find the root cause. It seems that the container reaches the Limits and not the JVM, but why? Can CPU throttling causes Memory issues? Throttling is an expected behavior for peaks to slow down. I do not expect any memory issues in that case.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for CPU throttling to indirectly cause memory issues by making garbage collection in the JVM less efficient or escalate an already inefficient memory usage, as such it may result in slower response times for your application, leading to more requests being queued up and more memory being used making the application store more objects in memory while waiting for requests to be processed.

The JVM flags that you have set are a good starting point. To further investigate any memory leaks you might want to use the followings to dump the heap on an OOM and analyze the dump with a tool like Java VisualVM to find the root cause.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/heapdump.bin
```

> Throttling is an expected behavior for peaks to slow down.

Yes, but I would consider CPU throttling more of a handbrake here and not the only *solution*. Instead I would implement an appropriate mechanism (like rate limiting, request queuing, circuit breakers, or backpressure throttling) either in the application or at the load balancer/reverse proxy level to prevent queues from forming.

Comment: the OOMKilled is a state from k8s. The JVM does not terminates, but the container. A Heap Dump would never be written, because the JVM Limits are not reached. The JVM limits are below the pod limits. k8s is terminating the container because of too high ram consumption.
I aggree with you, the throttling is not the only solution, nevertheless I cannot see the real reason for that behavior.

Comment: @NorbertKoch I see. Thanks for the hint. Would you mind sharing the name of the image (and the build file, e.g. Dockerfile) of your container? Are there other processes running in the container that also consume memory?

Comment: If you can easily recreate the peak/OOM case, can you exec into the container and run the following diagnostics and provide their outputs (just before the container gets killed)?

# garbage collection statistics
`jstat -gc 1`

# show the 3 memory intensive processes
`ps aux | sort -rnk 4 | head -3`

# show the total virtual memory used by those processes
`ps aux | sort -rnk 4 | head -3 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/status | grep VmSize`

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get events | grep Warning` after the container gets killed?

Comment: Btw different java images may have different versions of the JVM and its components, and different default configuration settings especially in terms of memory consumption and memory management. It'ld be worth trying to run the tests with different images also..

Comment: Thanks @KenanGüler. I'm currently on it to reproduce the issue. But it takes some time, then I will provide the requested information. Docker base image is: `eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine` with some permission stuff and the jar file as entrypoint. I provide all information immediatly after I gathered to reproduce the behavior manually.

Comment: The output of `kubectl top pod -n POD_NAMESPACE POD_NAME` would be of interest, if you have the [Kubernetes Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) installed on the cluster - again just before the container gets killed.

Comment: The `ps` related commands I provided might not work on `eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine`. You can use `ps a -o pid,vsz,rss,args | head -4 | tail -3 | sort -rnk 3` to retrieve *RSS* and *VSZ* related info though. Also if you are not able to reproduce this manually/easily, I'ld mount a temporary volume into the container (`emptyDir` would also do) and start the diagnostic relevant commands in the background (using `setsid` and `watch` may help) and redirect their output to a file (in the mounted volume). They'ld run until the container eventually gets killed...